# How to draw menu at the bottom of NavigationView?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Is it possible to make the menu appear at the bottom of the `NavigationView`, and not at the top.

I guess that I can put any Layout inside the `NavigationView`, and draw some buttons. But I would like to use the `app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"`, if possible.

[image]

Comment: You can check here how: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView

Comment: @Ricardo, thanks, but i need exactly DrawerLayout with the side NavigationView, and not BottomNavigationView.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that by creating `BottomSheetDialog` it behaves like ordinary Android dialog but it will appear on bottom. To make `BottomSheetDialog` works most important part is to add `app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"` to your `root view`. So basically create your desired layout add that line to `root view` and than inside code create `BottomSheetDialog`:

```
       //This is Java code but you can easily convert it to C#
       BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
       View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.yourLayoutHere, null);
       bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view);
       bottomSheetDialog.show();
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need exactly DrawerLayout with side NavigationView, not BottomSheetDialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to create custom navigation drawer.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <include layout="@layout/content_home" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <include layout="@layout/layout_navigation" />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Where `<include layout="@layout/layout_navigation" />` is the custom layout
for a menu where you can create a custom layout and add required textviews.
And then you can give gravity bottom to the parent of those textviews.

let me know if this doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks. But it looks like that, what I meant "I guess that I can put any Layout inside the NavigationView, and draw some buttons." Or, maybe I didn't understand you, and you can tell how to use [android menu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus) in that way?

Comment: You have to use the above method which is provided. else you cannot bring down your menu. it is easy to create custom layout inside a navigation. DM me if you have any issues.

Else here is the little hack. create empty menus before your menu in menu.xml file and don't give any text or icon. This is just a hack. and it will result in changing the position of menus in different devices.